# How to get the current directory on a class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, filepath, configuration-files

I've been looking around but I have not found a solution for this problem: I want to create a class library that has a configuration file under a sub-directory called Configuration. I want that class library to be deployed anywhere and I want it to find its configuration files by knowing its own location.

Previous attempts with `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` did not work.
It would return temp locations such as

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7c00e0a3\38789d63\assembly\dl3\9c0a23ff\18fb5feb_6ac3c901`

instead of the desired

`bin/Configuration` path.

So:

1. Can a class library be aware of its own location on disk?
2. How would I go about witting test scripts for this functionality since it seems that directories change based on how you run the app (debugging inside VS, deploying on IIS, etc)

Comment: Why not include the configuration in the application's app.config file and use ConfigurationManager in your class libraries?

Comment: You might want to clarify your question (for better searchability later) that this is ASP.NET. For desktop applications, GetExecutingAssembly() works just fine.

Comment: @Justin: I want the Class Library to be independent of the caller application.
@Stu: Both. I want to create a class library that could be used for both Console Apps and Web Apps. The class library should not care about who's calling it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This should work -

```
string assemblyFile = (
    new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
).AbsolutePath;
```

Comment: would: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().Location not give the same info...?

Comment: @dba not when there's shadow copying. try it in unit test, for example, and it'll be wrong

Answer (score 3):

The below code worked for me to get the physical path of the Images folder in-class library file.

```
string fullFilePath = Path.Combine((new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath.Split(new string[] { "/bin" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]
                          , "@/Images/test.png");
```

I hope, it will help someone.

Comment: I think this one is working for me, so thanks, @RajeevKumar